# When to use 별로 vs 그리?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

In the following sentences (from [duolingo](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/25207796)):

> 그것은 그리 안 좋아요.

I used 별로 instead of 그리 and got wrong.

But I'm not sure what is the difference between them and when I should use one over the other. Both seem to mean the same thing (at least from my dictionary).

So when should I use 그리 over the 별로 and vice versa?

Comment: If this is a typical example sentence you can find on duolingo, I'd advise staying away from it, because a native Korean speaker is very unlikely to utter "**그것은** 그리/별로 안 좋아요" unless they're translating from English.  We will simply omit "그것은" altogether.

Comment: You should not trust all Duolingo's feedback. The correct answers are *manually* put there, so it cannot have all the correct answers. For that sentence, both 별로 and 그리 sound correct to me.

Comment: @jick I know it. The system must be programmed as such since the translation from English always has a subject. But still, I keep using it as there is no good alternative...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost the same meaning if the sentence is not a question.

In my case, I would rather use `그리 안좋아요` when the thing is expected to be good but disappoints me actually.

The difference stands out if you're going to use it with questions:

`결혼하면 뭐가 그리 안좋아요?`

In a situation where you thought the marriage is not so bad, but someone told you it isn't good, you may ask with this sentence:

`결혼하면 뭐가 별로 안좋아요?`

You already know the marriage is bad and you're asking `what is so bad exactly?`.

Answer (score 0):

From Korean dictionary([별로](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/7c4360f9620a44cdabc3dc4a8b62ed9b), [그다지(`그리2` and `그리3` is `그다지1` and `그다지2`)](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/60728490375c4795b79c199276fb25c4), [그리](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/309ec3a1b9c9419db6c1927ab8cd2970))

word `별로` has meaning of somewhat compare or different(`별` of 별로 is 別, means different).

But well, I think they actually not that different, if `그리` used in meaning of `그리2`(`그다지1` : `in that way much`).

`그리1` means `(forms, shapes, etc) that way`, `그리3`(`그다지2`) means `that much`, and it is surely different from `별로`.

Sorry for my bad English, and please ask me again if you couldn't understand my answer.